# Copying Effects from Photoshop to After Effects

Tags: after-effects, effects, color-grading

I was wondering if it was possible to copy effects settings from photoshop to after effects?

Let's say I have a simple effect like "Levels" and I want to have the exact same values for the effect in after effects like in Photoshop without having to switch windows to copy the values one by one.

Comment: Have you tried saving the levels as an adjustment layer, importing the PSD In AE and checking if it comes through?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is to import the PSD into After Effects, which converts the PS effects to AE effects automatically.

Make sure your effects are all on adjustment layers before importing, and make sure your document mode is set to RGB. If your PS document is a different resolution than your AE comp, you may need to move the effects from the auto generated layers to a new solid inside AE. This will not work if you are using layer masks in PS to manipulate the Adjustment Layer visible regions.

Hope this helps!